# Node.js Get data from one client and send it to an other client

Tags: node.js

I just created a singleplayer Atari game with canvas and JS and got challenged to turn it into a multiplayer game.

So now I'm basically trying to get data from one client and send it to another client with Node.js.

I would just like a simple example on how this could work since I could only find complicated examples on the internet and I have pretty much zero experience with Node.js.

And as you could guess I want to exchange cordinates of elements between two clients.

Comment: you need a server sitting in between them to do this

Comment: Look into WebSockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use database to store data(cordinates) on one server and then any/allowed user can use/fetch cordinates from database for example.

---

**By user1** saving cordinates on server.

```
var express = require('express')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var router = express.Router()
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

router.post('/setCordinates',function(reqs,resp){


MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,database){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{

        var dataBases = database.db("myApp")
        // fetching user1 by some key **id** from data base
        dataBases.collection('userCordinate').find({'id':reqs.body.id}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }else if(result[0]){
               // if user1 cordinates are on server then will update to new one
                dataBases.collection('userCordinate').update({"id":reqs.body.id},{$set:{"cordinates":"X-Y"}})

            }else{
                                        dataBases.collection('userCordinates').insertOne(reqs.body)

            }
        })

    }
})
```

})

---

**to user2** getting cordinates from database from server

```
 var express = require('express')

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var router = express.Router()
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

router.post('/getCordinates',function(reqs,resp){


MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,database){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{

        var dataBases = database.db("myApp")
        // fetching user1 by some key **id** from data base to send it to user2
        dataBases.collection('userCordinate').find({'id':reqs.body.id}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }else if(result[0]){
               // user2 can get cordinates from database
                 resp.send(result[0].cordinates)
            }else{
                        resp.send({"No cordinates"})                
            }
        })

    }
})
})
```

---

> May be i am wrong but query time = 0 milliseconds approx. Which is
>   okay. If wrong then please comment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm going to check it out but I wanted to use Node.js without a Database because I have to update the cordinates every 10 miliseconds and I thought this is not very ressource friendly

Comment: Well your express server could store everything in memory, but there will still be latency from both the calls. 10ms is most likely optimistic, and I’m not sure where you got that number from. In competitive FPS games for example, the round trip time on a stable (playable with lag) connection  (client->sever->back) can be anywhere from 50-300ms. Human reaction time is on average somewhere just above 200ms.

Comment: @ chris 1  and @  Luca after reading your comments i was curious to know how much time it take to make query from data base you can see what i found in ans (going to edit that)

Comment: @chris Those 10ms are from an example on the Internet

Comment: @RajanLagah running actually productive and not on localhost where the clients are running will introduce the delay and the query time will absolutely not be 0ms. to see this just ping localhost, and then something like google.